# Python DataFrame periodic reset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reset

all, I have a Dataframe, say DF.  For the column of DF['weight'], I'd like to reset the rows between [n*7+1, n*7+6] to the value of row n*7.  That's to say, each whole week will use the same weight from each Monday.

I don't want to use loop, but as a newbie, I can't figure out the most efficient code.  Could someone help please?

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to assign every 7th weight to the next six rows.

```
df['weight_new'] = df.groupby(df.index//7)['weight'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
```

Comment: Just saw your answer, Scott.  Thanks much for the tip!  That's exactly what I wanted.